# Creating a directory in a subdirectory in AWS S3 is an error

Tags: amazon-s3

When I create a directory in the subdirectory of WS S3, I am prompted that my permission is incorrect, 
but my account has other permissions except for the delete permission of S3. Do I need to add the permission of other services?

How can I set permissions for other services if I want to add them?

I checked the official documents of AWS, but I still didn't find the solution I needed. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Please show us the permissions you have, what you are trying to do and the _exact_ error message you are receiving.

Comment: Side-note: Directories do not actually exist in Amazon S3. If you want to make a directory 'appear', then just create a zero-length object with the name of the directory. However, generally there should be on need to ever 'create' a directory.